# correlation between deffunctions and defrules CLIPS

Tags: clips

```
(deftemplate client
    (slot idClient (type INTEGER))
    (multislot nome)
    (multislot birthdate)
    (multislot registryCard)
    (multislot endOfRegistryCard))

(deffunction reservation(?idfunc)   
    (build (str-cat"(defrule existsClient
    (exists(client(idClient ?idfunc)))
    =>
    (printout t "exists" ?idfunc crlf))"
))

    (run)   
)
```

I made this deffunction and I want to see if exists the client with that idfunc that is received as parameter. what happens is that the defrule inside doesn't process this variable any thoughts how can i resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set condition (assert your idfunc) and then fire the execution of your "existsClient" rule (defined as rule and not inside your function). That would be a clearer design in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll directly define your rules rather than using a deffunction, but here's how you can do it both ways:

```
CLIPS> (clear) ; Create rule and run with deffunction
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate client
   (slot idClient (type INTEGER))
   (multislot nome)
   (multislot birthdate)
   (multislot registryCard)
   (multislot endOfRegistryCard))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction reservation (?idfunc)   
   (build (str-cat 
      "(defrule existsClient
          (exists (client (idClient " ?idfunc ")))
          =>
          (printout t \"exists " ?idfunc "\" crlf))"))
   (assert (client (idClient ?idfunc)))
   (run))
CLIPS> (reservation 2)
exists 2
CLIPS> (ppdefrule existsClient)
(defrule MAIN::existsClient
   (exists
        (client (idClient 2)))
   =>
   (printout t "exists 2" crlf))
CLIPS> (clear) ; Create rule directly
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate client
   (slot idClient (type INTEGER))
   (multislot nome)
   (multislot birthdate)
   (multislot registryCard)
   (multislot endOfRegistryCard))
CLIPS> 
(defrule existsClient
   (exists (client (idClient 2)))
   =>
   (printout t "exists 2" crlf))
CLIPS> (ppdefrule existsClient)
(defrule MAIN::existsClient
   (exists
        (client (idClient 2)))
   =>
   (printout t "exists 2" crlf))
CLIPS> (assert (client (idClient 2)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
exists 2
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks Gary helped a lot!